# Getting only sequences after groupby on a time series dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sequence

I have a time series dataframe for a e-commerce website which contains events (purchase, view, add). Every customer that enters the website, gets a user_session id. I made sequences of this dataframe by using this function:

```
grouped_df = ( 
    df1.sort_values(['event_time'],ascending=True)
       .groupby(by='user_session'['event_type']
       .apply(list)
       .to_frame(name='sequences')
)
```

This is the output:

|  | Sequences |
| --- | --- |
| 000AMhYaQu | [view, view, purchase] |
| 001HttdHUk | [view, add, view, purchase] |

The first things in the row is the user_session ID. after that, there are the sequences.

When I convert it to a csv file to use it as an input for my PrefixSpan, I get the following:

```
000AMhYaQu,['view']
000c34fa-991f-442a-8e07-8c472269bec6,['view']
001HttdHUk,['view']
001P7lK0Pt,"['view', 'view']"
001RxUtFJa,['view']
002DmERG1w,['view']
003QqC0jk0,['view']
003pEktS1X,"['view', 'view']"
```

How do I get the sequences without the user session ID values in front of it in the CSV file?

Comment: What does _"How do I get the sequences without the user session ID values in front of it in the CSV file?"_ exactly mean: Do you want `"['view', 'view']"` in the row or `view,view`?

Comment: Hi, I want to get view,view in the row. without the brackets so  it doesn't need to be a list. I have to get al the characters in the same list of every row.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
with open("file.csv", "w") as file:
    file.write("\n".join(grouped_df.sequences.str.join(",")))
```

The assumption here is that the elements of the column `sequences` are lists of strings.

Result for

```
grouped_df = 
                                      sequences
000AMhYaQu         ['view', 'view', 'purchase']
001HttdHUk  ['view', 'add', 'view', 'purchase']
```

is a file `file.csv` that contains

```
view,view,purchase
view,add,view,purchase
```

If you need all the trailing commas (for rows with a sub-max number of items), then you could do:

```
grouped_df.sequences.str.join(",").str.split(",", expand=True).to_csv(
    "file.csv", header=None, index=False
)
```

Result here is:

```
view,view,purchase,
view,add,view,purchase
```

Comment: @RobinvanHeesch If this was helpful please consider accepting/upvoting (see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).